# Pandas - Extract common substring between 2 columns

Tags: python

I have 2 dataframes, lets call them A and B. What I want to do is create a second column in DF A that contains the common substrings between the 2 DFs.

**DF: A**

| String |
| --- |
| 012IREze |
| SecondString |
| LastEntry |

**DF: B**

| String |
| --- |
| IREPP |
| StringNumber2 |
| LastEntry123 |

**Desired Output**

| String | Common String |
| --- | --- |
| 012IREze | IRE |
| SecondString | String |
| LastEntry111 | LastEntry |

I have found the below code online, but I can't get it working when dealing with columns

```
match = SequenceMatcher(None, string1, string2).find_longest_match(0, len(string1), 0, len(string2))

print(match)  # -> Match(a=0, b=15, size=9)
print(string1[match.a: match.a + match.size])  # -> apple pie
print(string2[match.b: match.b + match.size])  # -> apple pie
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, one method is to inner join by index the two dataframes and apply a custom function to the columns

**Code**

```
def lcs(x, y):
        '''
            Custom function to find LCS between strings x, y
        '''
        if pd.isna(x) or pd.isna(y):
            return ""

        match = SequenceMatcher(None, x, y).find_longest_match(0, len(x), 0, len(y))
        if match.size > 0:
            return x[match.a:match.a + match.size]
        else:
            return ""
        
def lcs_frames(dfa, dfb):
    '''
        Finds longest common substring of each row of dfa in dfb
        
        If one dataframe is longer than the other, result will be an empty string in dfa for
        unmatched rows
        
        Approach
        - 'String' is the column name in the two data frames to perform an LCS
        - Inner join of the dataframes so we have all the columns in one dataframe
        - Columns for LCS will be String_A and String_B after the join
        - Perform LCS on column String_A and String_B
    '''
    
    dfa['LCS'] = (dfa.join(dfb, lsuffix = "_A", rsuffix = "_B")    # inner join by index of dfa & dfb
            .apply(lambda row: lcs(row["String_A"], row["String_B"]), axis = 1))   # apply lcs function


    return dfa
```

**Example Usage**

```
sa = '''String
012IREze
SecondString
LastEntry
random'''

sb = '''String
IREPP
StringNumber2
LastEntry123
blue'''

dfa = pd.read_csv(StringIO(sa), sep = '\n')
dfb = pd.read_csv(StringIO(sb), sep = '\n')

# Perform LCS on dataframes
lcs_frames(dfa, dfb)

print(dfa)
```

**Output**

```
String            LCS
0   012IREze      IRE
1   SecondString  String
2   LastEntry     LastEntry
3   random
```

**Find Best Match**

For each row in first dataframe, following finds best match in 2nd.

```
import pandas as pd
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

def lcs(x, y):
        '''
            Custom function to find LCS between strings x, y
        '''
        if pd.isna(x) or pd.isna(y):
            return ""

        match = SequenceMatcher(None, x, y).find_longest_match(0, len(x), 0, len(y))
        if match.size > 0:
            return x[match.a:match.a + match.size]
        else:
            return ""
        
def lcs_search(dfa, dfb):
    '''
        Finds longest common substring of each row of dfa in dfb
        
        If one dataframe is longer than the other, result will be an empty string in dfa for
        unmatched rows
        
        Approach
        - String is the column in the two data frames to perform an LCS
        - Inner join of the dataframes so we have all the columns in one dataframe
        - Columns for LCS will be String_A and String_B after the join
        - Perform LCS on column String_A and String_B
    '''
     def lcs_find(target):
        '''
            Finds best match in db['String'] based upon length of match
        '''
        return max((lcs(target, x) for x in dfb['String']), key = len)
    
    dfa['LCS'] = dfa['String'].apply(lcs_find)

    return dfa
```

*Example*

```
from io import StringIO

sa = '''String
012IREze
SecondString
LastEntry
random'''

sb = '''String
IREPP
StringNumber2
LastEntry123
012IREze
Second
LastEntry Today'''

dfa = pd.read_csv(StringIO(sa), sep = '\n')
dfb = pd.read_csv(StringIO(sb), sep = '\n')

print(lcs_search(dfa, dfb))
```

*Output*

```
    String         LCS
0   012IREze       012IREze
1   SecondString   String
2   LastEntry      LastEntry
3   random         nd
```

Comment: Thank you. The issue with this is that I think both DFs have to be of the same length?

Comment: @PythonBeginner  -- the current code uses the length of the shorter one.  Do you need a solution where it's based on the length of A, which is where the result is going?

Comment: @PythonBeginner updated so to work with dataframes of different lengths.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I was looking for. Out of curiosity is there also a way to do it which isn't on a row to row basis. e.g if "012IREze" in dfa on the first row and "IREPP" was in dfb on the 4th row, is there a way to output the common substring in dfa in this scenario as "IRE"?

Comment: @PythonBeginner to compare a particular row in dfa (say 0), with a particular row in dfb (say 2),  you could use the lcs function in the answer with Pandas loc function to select the row/column value from the dataframe. 
 Thus: `lcs(dfa.loc[0, "String"], dfb.loc[2, "String"])` which returns '12' in this case.

Comment: I don't want to specify a row. At the moment the code you gave in the answer compares the first row in dfa with the first row in dfb etc. My question is, is there a way to take the first row value in dfa and iterate through dfb to get the longest common substring, and do this for all values in dfa

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247303/discussion-between-darrylg-and-pythonbeginner).